# Spring Web Sockets over AWS Application Load Balancer not working

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer

I have configured spring with web sockets, including rabbit mq on the back end and I can confirm that I can send push messages to the browser.

And using SockJS on the front end.

Up until now I have been using the classic load balancer.
I am trying to get web sockets to work on AWS. I have upgraded to the Application Load Balancer but I still get Bad Request response when I try to make the web socket connection to:

> ws://XXXX.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/spring/hello/870/sbmdv5tn/websocket

That call still gives 400 Bad Request response...

And I see

> Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null

Errors on the back end...

Answer (score 0):

It has to do the fact that the a connection upgrade is requested and these upgrade requests occur "per hop".

In my scenario I am running with apache in front of tomcat and in order for tomcat to receive these upgrade headers I need to enable web socket tunnelling on the apache proxy such that apache will simply pass through the upgrade request.

UPDATE:
Although a better solution is to bypass apache altogether and go straight to tomcat - that is configure the load balancer to route to port 8080 and not port 80. I suspect the reason elastic beanstalk does not do this by default because it then requires a load balancer - and if you only want single instance you don't need a load balancer.